# Poner un Favicon Animado que se pueda ver en Google

Tags: html, web

Quiero poner un favicon animado, con extensión **.gif** y me preguntaba si este era compatible con Google. He estado viendo, y dice que es compatible con FireFox únicamente los favicons animados, pero no encontré que pasaba con google.

No adjunto código, porque a mi entender no es necesario.

Saludos!
Espero la respuesta.

Comment: Creo que no es posible con gif, pero si con formato svg, en [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952907/what-is-the-best-practice-for-creating-a-favicon-on-a-web-site/68637634#68637634) en la versión en inglés tienes un ejemplo

Comment: Google Chrome no acepta formatos de imáganes animadas en el favicon, pero se puede animar un favicon mediante Javascript, animándolo frame a frame. Necesitarías cambiar la imagen del favicon varias veces por segundo.
Aquí hay un tutorial (en inglés) que indica como hacerlo: https://css-tricks.com/the-making-of-an-animated-favicon/

Comment: Gracias!!! Saludos!